# Module can't use multiple objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, node-modules

I have a module created using module.exports and I can't use multiple javascript objects at my module

that's my "app.js" file:

```
const object2csv = require('./object2csv.js');
  object2csv(
      { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }
  )
```

and that's my "module.js" file:

```
module.exports = function (arr){
console.log(arr)
}
```

output:

```
{ id: 1 }
```

How can I use my all objects?
Can I use forEach in modules?
Please answer with examples I'm newbie.

Answer (score 0):

you should send them as array

```
const object2csv = require('./object2csv.js');
object2csv([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]);
```

Comment: yeah I know but I need them as object. Because I'll convert them to array in my module for automation.